# Does caching(APC) of an instance of Zend_Acl affect security?

Tags: security, zend-acl, zend-cache

It wouldnt make it easier to do something nasty, would it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nope, should be totally save.
the cache is on the server side after all. as long as there is no way to get access to the underlying structure (ie, shell access to your server) it should be safe.

and if someone gets access to your server, then the apc security is your least worry ;)